# How to correctly arrange data for keras.model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working in a neural network using keras (from tensorflow) for a college project.
I'm pretty new to the library, so I don't really know how should I feed the data into the model in order for the training to work. I've been searching the internet for hours
and I can't find a proper tutorial / documentation on how to do it.

Here's the model I'm using, one of the simplest possible ones:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(20, input_dim=1,activation = activations.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=  activations.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation= activations.sigmoid)
])

model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

The input to the network is a list of 20 floats, and the output a list of 8 floats ranged from 0 to 1 (confidence level), so I think this model is OK, please let me know if I'm wrong.

Here's a diagram of the model i'm trying to build and train:
[image: network]

Let's say I have:

- 10 input examples (10 lists of 20 floats) for the expected output [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
- 10 input examples for the expect output [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
- ...
- 10 input examples for the expected output [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

How should I prepare this data in order to use it with

`model.fit(training_inputs,expected_outputs,epochs = NUM_EPOCHS)` ?

What should training_inputs exactly be? and expected_outputs?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have two issues in your model. According to your description, your input data is 20-dimensional, so in the first layer you should have `input_dim=20`. Then, you have a cross-entropy loss, so I'm assuming that you are training a 8-class classifier. If that's the case, then instead of `keras.layers.Dense(8, activation= activations.sigmoid)` you should use

```
keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=None),
keras.layers.Softmax()
```

as that ensures that you get a distribution over classes for each input data point.

Now regarding your input data question, `training_inputs` should a tensor (or numpy array, which will be readily converted) with shape `(n_points, 20)` in your case. Accordingly, `expected_outputs` should have shape `(n_points, 8)`. So, just concatenate/stack your input data along the first dimension (`axis=0`), such that each row corresponds to your 20-dimensional data points. You do the same for `expected_outputs`, maybe something like,

```
expected_outputs = np.r_[
    np.tile([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], (10, 1)),
    np.tile([[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]], (10, 1)),
    ...
    np.tile([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]], (10, 1)),
]
```

Remember to set `batch_size` and `shuffle`!